# MongoDB encountering configuration issue when running "mongod"

Tags: mongodb, percona

Why do I get this when running "mongod" on my command line?
What does it mean, and how to fix this issue,
I have configured my mongod.conf properly and I can run my `mongo --username --password` without any problem but when running the mongo using "`mongod`" this is showing up.
I need to run mongod --encryption options for my database so that encryption will be enabled.
I know it can be done in the mongod.conf file however doing it there does not work and does not give much error to understand the problem.

```
 {
        "t": {
            "$date": "2021-04-19T13:25:02.114+00:00"
        },
        "s": "I",
        "c": "CONTROL",
        "id": 23285,
        "ctx": "main",
        "msg": "Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"
    } {
        "t": {
            "$date": "2021-04-19T13:25:02.115+00:00"
        },
        "s": "W",
        "c": "ASIO",
        "id": 22601,
        "ctx": "main",
        "msg": "No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"
    } {
        "t": {
            "$date": "2021-04-19T13:25:02.115+00:00"
        },
        "s": "I",
        "c": "NETWORK",
        "id": 4648601,
        "ctx": "main",
        "msg": "Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."
    } {
        "t": {
            "$date": "2021-04-19T13:25:02.116+00:00"
        },
        "s": "I",
        "c": "STORAGE",
        "id": 4615611,
        "ctx": "initandlisten",
        "msg": "MongoDB starting",
        "attr": {
            "pid": 29859,
            "port": 27017,
            "dbPath": "/data/db",
            "architecture": "64-bit",
            "host": "ip-10-235-200-251.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal"
        }
    } {
        "t": {
            "$date": "2021-04-19T13:25:02.116+00:00"
        },
        "s": "I",
        "c": "CONTROL",
        "id": 23403,
        "ctx": "initandlisten",
        "msg": "Build Info",
        "attr": {
            "buildInfo": {
                "version": "4.4.4-6",
                "gitVersion": "f3dd4bc7c7500705a537de40bb4d6127ba498bd3",
                "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017",
                "modules": [],
                "allocator": "tcmalloc",
                "environment": {
                    "distarch": "x86_64",
                    "target_arch": "x86_64"
                }
            }
        }
    } {
        "t": {
            "$date": "2021-04-19T13:25:02.116+00:00"
        },
        "s": "I",
        "c": "CONTROL",
        "id": 51765,
        "ctx": "initandlisten",
        "msg": "Operating System",
        "attr": {
            "os": {
                "name": "Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)",
                "version": "Kernel 4.14.198-152.320.amzn2.x86_64"
            }
        }
    } {
        "t": {
            "$date": "2021-04-19T13:25:02.116+00:00"
        },
        "s": "I",
        "c": "CONTROL",
        "id": 21951,
        "ctx": "initandlisten",
        "msg": "Options set by command line",
        "attr": {
            "options": {}
        }
    } {
        "t": {
            "$date": "2021-04-19T13:25:02.116+00:00"
        },
        "s": "E",
        "c": "NETWORK",
        "id": 23024,
        "ctx": "initandlisten",
        "msg": "Failed to unlink socket file",
        "attr": {
            "path": "/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock",
            "error": "Operation not permitted"
        }
    } {
        "t": {
            "$date": "2021-04-19T13:25:02.116+00:00"
        },
        "s": "F",
        "c": "-",
        "id": 23091,
        "ctx": "initandlisten",
        "msg": "Fatal assertion",
        "attr": {
            "msgid": 40486,
            "file": "src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp",
            "line": 919
        }
    } {
        "t": {
            "$date": "2021-04-19T13:25:02.116+00:00"
        },
        "s": "F",
        "c": "-",
        "id": 23092,
        "ctx": "initandlisten",
        "msg": "\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"
    }
```

Thank You I am new to this I hope someone  can help me.

Comment: which mongodb version do you use ?

Comment: i am using version 4.4

Comment: Try to start from scratch, install is as linux service see examples here based on which linux distro do you use: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/